# Correctly performing special method lookup

Tags: python

If I want to look up a special method of an object, I can do it on the object or its type. Neither option seems to be correct, though.

```
def lookup_add(o):
    return o.__add__
def lookup_sub(o):
    return type(o).__sub__

class Foo(type):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented

class Bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = Foo

    def __add__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented

baz = Bar()

lookup_add(Bar) # Produces wrong method
lookup_sub(baz) # Should raise an error. Instead, produces wrong method.
```

`lookup_add` looks it up on the object. It works correctly for `lookup_add(baz)`, returning a bound method object for `baz`'s method, but it produces the wrong result for `lookup_add(Bar)`.

`lookup_sub` looks it up on the type. It works correctly for `lookup_sub(Bar)`, returning an unbound method object for `Bar`'s method, but it produces the wrong result for `lookup_sub(baz)`.

I could try `functools.partial(operator.add, o)`, but that doesn't really look up `o`'s method. If `o` doesn't actually implement `__add__`, this attempt won't produce the error I want.

Is there a good way to replicate the interpreter's special method lookup behavior?

Comment: What is the correct behavior? I don't see how `lookup_add(Bar)` could get a bound method from a class object.

Comment: Very interesting... curious how to solve this issue.

Comment: @li.davidm: I want a function that produces, for any object `o`, a return value representing the `__add__` method that gets called when you do `o + whatever`, or raises an error if no such method exists. It's not important whether the result is a bound or unbound method. (Note that I'm aware of `__radd__` and `__iadd__`; I specifically want to look up `__add__`. It might've been better to pick methods like `__pos__` or `__neg__` for the example.)

Comment: I see. So `lookup_add(Bar)` should give you `Bar.__add__(Class2)`, i.e. `Bar + Class2`?

Comment: @li.davidm: It should give the method that gets called when you do `Bar + Class2`. That method happens to be `Foo.__add__`.

Comment: how about searching for the method in dir(baz)?

Comment: @Mai: dir just returns a list of attribute names; it doesn't help with lookup.

Comment: How about calling the method to get the NotImplemented value? I guess, Python tries to call methods to get NotImplemented value

Comment: @Roman: I think it's more important to get the TypeError raised in this case.

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve? This is the hunt for a solution where there doesn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could combine your two using `isinstance`:

```
def lookup_method(obj, method):
    if not isinstance(obj, type):
        return getattr(obj, method, None)
    return getattr(type(obj), method, None)

>>> print(lookup_method(Bar, '__add__'))
<unbound method Foo.__add__>
>>> print(lookup_method(baz, '__add__'))
<bound method Bar.__add__ of <__main__.Bar object at 0x23f27d0>>
>>> print(lookup_method(baz, '__sub__'))
None
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. If someone sets `baz.__add__ = 3`, this returns `3` instead of a method.

Comment: In that case, you could add a check using `callable`.

Comment: `bar.__add__ = lambda x: 4`, then.

Comment: Oh... so you want what the instance would have given without any modifications (because technically that is now the instance's add method). Hmm.

Comment: It's not the method that'll get called if you do `bar + something`. I want the method Python will actually use for addition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it. The trick is to always get the type's (unbound) method and bind it:

```
import types

def special_lookup_mimic(obj, name):
    if not hasattr(obj, name):
        raise TypeError("No method of that name")

    meth = getattr(obj, name)
    if not isinstance(meth, types.MethodType):
        raise TypeError("Expected method")

    #always look-up the type's method
    cls = obj.__class__
    return getattr(cls, name).__get__(obj, cls)
```

Demo:

```
class Foo(type):
    def __add__(cls, other):
        print 'Foo().__add__'
        return 999

class Bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = Foo

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __add__(self, other):
        print 'Bar(%d).__add__' % (self.id,)
        return self.id

b1 = Bar(1)
b2 = Bar(2)

b1 + 10; special_lookup_mimic(b1, '__add__')(10)
b2 + 10; special_lookup_mimic(b2, '__add__')(10)

b1.__add__ = b2.__add__

b1 + 10; special_lookup_mimic(b1, '__add__')(10)
b2 + 10; special_lookup_mimic(b2, '__add__')(10)

Bar + 10; special_lookup_mimic(Bar, '__add__')(10)

def patched_add(num):
    def patch_add(cls, other):
        print "Patched add '%d'" % (num,)
        return num
    return patch_add

print "Patching Bar.__add__..."
Bar.__add__ = patched_add(1337)

b1 + 10; special_lookup_mimic(b1, '__add__')(10)
b2 + 10; special_lookup_mimic(b2, '__add__')(10)
Bar + 10; special_lookup_mimic(Bar, '__add__')(10)

print "Patching Foo.__add__..."
Foo.__add__ = patched_add(10000)

b1 + 10; special_lookup_mimic(b1, '__add__')(10)
b2 + 10; special_lookup_mimic(b2, '__add__')(10)
Bar + 10; special_lookup_mimic(Bar, '__add__')(10)
```

Output:

```
Bar(1).__add__
Bar(1).__add__
Bar(2).__add__
Bar(2).__add__
Bar(1).__add__
Bar(1).__add__
Bar(2).__add__
Bar(2).__add__
Foo().__add__
Foo().__add__
Patching Bar.__add__...
Patched add '1337'
Patched add '1337'
Patched add '1337'
Patched add '1337'
Foo().__add__
Foo().__add__
Patching Foo.__add__...
Patched add '1337'
Patched add '1337'
Patched add '1337'
Patched add '1337'
Patched add '10000'
Patched add '10000'
```

Comment: Close, but there are still edge cases where it fails. For example, if you monkey-patch one instance's method onto another instance with `x.__add__ = y.__add__`, this will return `y`'s method instead of what Python would use for `x + something`. It's frustratingly difficult to just get Python's special method lookup behavior; you'd think there would be a simple recipe or a library function somewhere.

Comment: @user2357112: i think i got it... does this work for all the cases you can think of?