# How to get the bound method derived from a metaclass when the class has a method of the same name

Tags: python, methods, instance, metaclass

Consider the following case:

```
class Meta(type):
    def shadowed(cls):
        print "Meta.shadowed()"
    def unshadowed(cls):
        print "Meta.unshadowed()"

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def shadowed(self):
        print "Foo.shadowed()"
```

I can call get the bound method `unshadowed` on `Foo` and it works fine:

```
>>> Foo.unshadowed
<bound method Meta.unshadowed of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> Foo.unshadowed()
Meta.unshadowed()
```

However, I can't seem to get the bound method `shadowed` on `Foo` - it directs me rather to the unbound method which must be called with instances of `Foo`:

```
>>> Foo.shadowed
<unbound method Foo.shadowed>
>>> Foo.shadowed()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo.shadowed()
TypeError: unbound method shadowed() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Is there any way to get `<bound method Meta.shadowed of <class '__main__.Foo'>>`?

Comment: So you want to have 2 methods -- e.g. `Foo.shadowed` and `Foo().shadowed`?

Comment: Sounds a lot like the question I just asked (though not a duplicate).

Comment: @user2357112: Yea I derived this question from yours. if this one has an answer then we can figure out an answer to yours as well

Comment: Out of curiousity. Why would you need this ?

Comment: @karthikr: to be able to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972412/correctly-performing-special-method-lookup) - it seems the `+` operator correctly looks up the shadowed method and I was wondering how to do the same 'manually'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems one potential answer (maybe not the best) is found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method) on how to bind unbound methods. So we can do this:

```
>>> Meta.shadowed.__get__(Foo, Meta)()
Meta.shadowed()
```

Better demonstration:

```
class Meta(type):
    def shadowed(cls):
        print "Meta.shadowed() on %s" % (cls.__name__,)
    def unshadowed(cls):
        print "Meta.unshadowed() on %s" % (cls.__name__,)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def shadowed(self):
        print "Foo.shadowed()"

class Bar(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

Bar.unshadowed()                   #Meta.unshadowed() on Bar 
Bar.shadowed()                     #Meta.shadowed() on Bar
Foo.unshadowed()                   #Meta.unshadowed() on Foo
#Foo.shadowed()                    #TypeError    
Meta.shadowed.__get__(Foo, Meta)() #Meta.shadowed() on Foo
```